# How to convert a ByteString value to a JSVal

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, ghcjs-dom

In the module *GHCJS.DOM.JSFFI.Generated.CanvasRenderingContext2D* there is the function `putImageData` with the following type:

```
putImageData ::
  Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m =>
  CanvasRenderingContext2D
  -> Maybe GHCJS.DOM.Types.ImageData -> Float -> Float -> m ()
```

The second parameter has the type `Maybe GHCJS.DOM.Types.ImageData`.
This type is defined in the module *GHCJS.DOM.Types* as a newtype wrapper around a JSVal value:

```
newtype ImageData = ImageData {unImageData :: GHCJS.Prim.JSVal}
```

I have a value of type `ByteString` that has always 4 bytes with the RGBA values of each pixel. How to I convert my ByteString value to a GHCJS.Prim.JSVal?

Comment: what sort of JSVal would you expect `ByteString` to be? - one thing you can do for sure is encode it base64 and make a JSString out of it - this would be my choice.

Comment: I have no familiarity with this, but I think the JS value must be in the right format for this to work. Maybe the docs state which is the right format, e.g. array-of-array-of-integers ? Or a JS object of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As K.A. Buhr pointed out, after converting the `ByteString` to a `Uint8ClampedArray`, you can pass the clamped array to `newImageData` to get the desired `ImageData` object.

You can use an inline Javascript function to generate the `Uint8ClampedArray`.  To pass a `ByteString` through the Javascript FFI, use `Data.ByteString.useAsCStringLen` .

The code below shows how to do this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE JavaScriptFFI #-}
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

import Reflex.Dom
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import GHCJS.DOM.ImageData (newImageData)
import GHCJS.DOM.HTMLCanvasElement (getContext)
import GHCJS.DOM.JSFFI.Generated.CanvasRenderingContext2D (putImageData)
import GHCJS.DOM.Types (CanvasRenderingContext2D(..), castToHTMLCanvasElement, Uint8ClampedArray(..))
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr)
import GHCJS.Types (JSVal)
import GHCJS.Marshal.Pure (pFromJSVal, pToJSVal)
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text as T (Text, pack)
import Data.ByteString as BS (ByteString, pack, useAsCStringLen)

-- Some code and techniques taken from these sites:
-- http://lpaste.net/154691
-- https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1032978/Simple-Canvas-Example/

-- import inline Javascript code as Haskell function : jsUint8ClampedArray
foreign import javascript unsafe 
    -- Arguments
    --     pixels : Ptr a -- Pointer to a ByteString 
    --     len    : JSVal -- Number of pixels
    "(function(){ return new Uint8ClampedArray($1.u8.slice(0, $2)); })()" 
    jsUint8ClampedArray :: Ptr a -> JSVal -> IO JSVal

-- takes pointer and length arguments as passed by useAsCStringLen
newUint8ClampedArray :: (Ptr a, Int) -> IO Uint8ClampedArray
newUint8ClampedArray (pixels, len) = 
    pFromJSVal <$> jsUint8ClampedArray pixels (pToJSVal len)

canvasAttrs :: Int -> Int -> Map T.Text T.Text
canvasAttrs w h =    ("width" =: T.pack (show w)) 
                  <> ("height" =: T.pack (show h))

main = mainWidget $ do
    -- first, generate some test pixels
    let boxWidth = 120
        boxHeight = 30
        boxDataLen = boxWidth*boxHeight*4 -- 4 bytes per pixel

        reds = take boxDataLen $ concat $ repeat [0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff]
        greens = take boxDataLen $ concat $ repeat [0x00,0xff,0x00,0xff]
        blues = take boxDataLen $ concat $ repeat [0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff]

        pixels = reds ++ greens ++ blues
        image = BS.pack pixels -- create a ByteString with the pixel data.

    -- create Uint8ClampedArray representation of pixels
    imageArray <- liftIO $ BS.useAsCStringLen image newUint8ClampedArray

    let imageWidth = boxWidth
        imageHeight = (length pixels `div` 4) `div` imageWidth

    -- use Uint8ClampedArray representation of pixels to create ImageData
    imageData <- newImageData (Just imageArray) (fromIntegral imageWidth) (fromIntegral imageHeight)

    -- demonstrate the imageData is what we expect by displaying it.
    (element, _) <- elAttr' "canvas" (canvasAttrs 300 200) $ return ()
    let canvasElement = castToHTMLCanvasElement(_element_raw element)
    elementContext <-  getContext canvasElement ("2d" :: String)

    let renderingContext = CanvasRenderingContext2D elementContext
    putImageData renderingContext (Just imageData) 80 20
```

Here's a link to a repository with the example code: https://github.com/dc25/stackOverflow__how-to-convert-a-bytestring-value-to-a-jsval

Here's a link to a live demo : https://dc25.github.io/stackOverflow__how-to-convert-a-bytestring-value-to-a-jsval/

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Looks like my original answer was too GHC centric.  Added an untested fix that might work for GHCJS.

**Edit #2:** Added my `stack.yaml` file for the example.

You can use `GHCJS.DOM.ImageData.newImageData` to construct the `ImageData` object.  It requires the data to be a `GHCJS.DOM.Types.Uint8ClampedArray` (which is a byte array in RGBA format).

There are conversion functions in `GHCJS.Buffer` from `ByteString`s to `Buffer`s (via `fromByteString`) and from there to typed arrays (e.g., `getUint8Array`).  They do the conversion directly under GHCJS, and even under plain GHC they use a base64 conversion as an intermediary which should be pretty fast.  Unfortunately, the conversion function `getUint8ClampedArray` isn't included (and for plain GHC, it looks like `fromByteString` might be broken anyway -- in jsaddle 0.8.3.0, it's calling the wrong JavaScript helper function).

For plain GHC, the following seems to work (the first line is copied from `fromByteString` with the helper renamed from the apparently incorrect `h$newByteArrayBase64String`):

```
uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString :: ByteString -> GHCJSPure (Uint8ClampedArray)
uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString bs = GHCJSPure $ do
  buffer <- SomeBuffer <$> jsg1 "h$newByteArrayFromBase64String"
                                (decodeUtf8 $ B64.encode bs)
  arrbuff <- ghcjsPure (getArrayBuffer (buffer :: MutableBuffer))
  liftDOM (Uint8ClampedArray <$> new (jsg "Uint8ClampedArray") [pToJSVal arrbuff])
```

Here is an untested GHCJS version that may work.  If they fix the above-mentioned jsaddle bug, it should work under plain GHC, too:

```
uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString :: ByteString -> GHCJSPure (Uint8ClampedArray)
uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString bs = GHCJSPure $ do
  (buffer,_,_) <- ghcjsPure (fromByteString bs)
  buffer' <- thaw buffer
  arrbuff <- ghcjsPure (getArrayBuffer buffer')
  liftDOM (Uint8ClampedArray <$> new (jsg "Uint8ClampedArray") [pToJSVal arrbuff])
```

I don't have a running GHCJS installation, but here's a complete working example I tested using JSaddle+Warp under plain GHC which seems to work okay (i.e., if you point a browser at localhost:6868, it displays a 3x4 image on the canvas element):

```
module Main where

import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Text.Encoding (decodeUtf8)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Base64 as B64 (encode)
import Language.Javascript.JSaddle (js, js1, jss, jsg, jsg1,
                                    new, pToJSVal, GHCJSPure(..), ghcjsPure, JSM,
                                    fromJSVal, toJSVal, Object)
import Language.Javascript.JSaddle.Warp (run)
import JSDOM.Types (liftDOM, Uint8ClampedArray(..), RenderingContext(..))
import JSDOM.ImageData
import JSDOM.HTMLCanvasElement
import JSDOM.CanvasRenderingContext2D
import GHCJS.Buffer (getArrayBuffer, MutableBuffer)
import GHCJS.Buffer.Types (SomeBuffer(..))
import Control.Lens ((^.))

main :: IO ()
main = run 6868 $ do
  let smallImage = BS.pack [0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,  0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,  0xff,0x00,0x00,0xff,
                            0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,  0x00,0xff,0x00,0xff,  0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,
                            0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,  0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,  0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,
                            0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff,  0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,  0x00,0x00,0xff,0xff]
  img <- makeImageData 3 4 smallImage
  doc <- jsg "document"
  doc ^. js "body" ^. jss "innerHTML" "<canvas id=c width=10 height=10></canvas>"
  Just canvas <- doc ^. js1 "getElementById" "c" >>= fromJSVal
  Just ctx <- getContext canvas "2d" ([] :: [Object])
  let ctx' = CanvasRenderingContext2D (unRenderingContext ctx)
  putImageData ctx' img 3 4
  return ()

uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString :: ByteString -> GHCJSPure (Uint8ClampedArray)
uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString bs = GHCJSPure $ do
  buffer <- SomeBuffer <$> jsg1 "h$newByteArrayFromBase64String"
                                (decodeUtf8 $ B64.encode bs)
  arrbuff <- ghcjsPure (getArrayBuffer (buffer :: MutableBuffer))
  liftDOM (Uint8ClampedArray <$> new (jsg "Uint8ClampedArray") [pToJSVal arrbuff])

makeImageData :: Int -> Int -> ByteString -> JSM ImageData
makeImageData width height dat
  = do dat' <- ghcjsPure (uint8ClampedArrayFromByteString dat)
       newImageData dat' (fromIntegral width) (Just (fromIntegral height))
```

To build this, I used the following `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-8.12
extra-deps:
- ghcjs-dom-0.8.0.0
- ghcjs-dom-jsaddle-0.8.0.0
- jsaddle-0.8.3.0
- jsaddle-warp-0.8.3.0
- jsaddle-dom-0.8.0.0
- ref-tf-0.4.0.1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your excellent example. I think that we are working in different universes: You are using `JSDOM.ImageData` and `JSDOM.HTMLCanvasElement`. However I'm using `GHCJS.DOM.Types` and `GHCJS.DOM.JSFFI.Generated.CanvasRenderingContext2D`. I don't yet know how the two unverses are related and how I can apply your solution in my universe. I'm using `GHCJS.DOM` because at the end of the day my example should work in reflex-dom.

Comment: I tried to setup a stack.yaml file to really compile and execute your full example. Unfortunately I failed. What is the Stackage LTS version you used to test your code? What are the commit ids of reflex and reflex-dom?

Comment: I added my `stack.yaml`.  (Note that it didn't use `reflex` which, given its dependence on `ghcjs-base`, is probably truly GHCJS-specific.)

Comment: reflex-dom has a [Foreign.JavaScript.Utils.bsToArrayBuffer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-core-0.6.1.0/docs/Foreign-JavaScript-Utils.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hoogle to find a function by it's type signature `ByteString -> GHCJS.Prim.JSVal`. https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.11/hoogle?q=ByteString+-%3E+GHCJS.Prim.JSVal

Which has this in the results:
https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.11/ghcjs-base-stub-0.1.0.2/GHCJS-Prim.html#v:toJSString

```
toJSString :: String -> JSVal
```

So now you just need a function to do `ByteString -> String`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. If you click at the *Source* link in your result link, then you see it says: `toJSString = const jsNull`. So it always results just in an empty JS string!